# "It's stressful this managing lark, ..." meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Sorry I was a bit short with you earlier, Potter," she said abruptly. "**It's stressful this managing lark**, you know, I'm starting to think I was a bit hard on Wood sometimes." She was watching Ron over the rim of her goblet with a slight frown on her face.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

What does "It's stressful this managing lark" mean? Does it mean *this managing lark is stressful*?

Comment: The structure of this very sentence is analyzed in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=urVhDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT160&lpg=PT160&dq=%22it%27s+stressful+this%22&source=bl&ots=pw8Yvp7Iqh&sig=ACfU3U1g4hi2yhju9-acK5T6cQBvURMCYg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO5YGsuqbgAhVvUN8KHW-eARwQ6AEwCnoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22it's%20stressful%20this%22&f=false).

Comment: Yes, it means 'this managing lark is stressful'.

Comment: The book linked by Alex doesn't mention it so I assume I'm incorrect but I would have thought a comma was required after stressful.  If I was speaking I would always pause slightly between the two clauses.  I don't think I've ever had cause to write such a sentence but if I did I would replicate the pause with a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's an epitome of something called *extraposed clause* as in such cases, the *dummy* 'it' leads the sentence.

Let me try an example where clause is used as a subject.

> That the restaurants are closed on Sundays is nonsensical.

Here, if you want to make it extraposed, you write -

> It is nonsensical that the restaurants are closed on Sundays.

A bit closer to your example can be found [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/extraposition-grammar-term-1690626).

> ***What they are proposing to do is*** horrifying.

but then, extraposing would be...

> ***It's*** horrifying ***what they are proposing to do.***

So, yes, it means what you got it!

Comment: But "this managing lark" is not a clause.

Comment: @dan that's what the analysis on that sentence says in the book as stated in the comment of Alex. There it says that *the noun phrase takes a different form.* Check the link.

Comment: The passage to which Alex's comment linked indicates that the sentence in the question could be classified as a dislocation rather than an extraposed clause. What I take from the book is that there is not universal agreement on this classification.

Comment: @DavidK true that! In fact, I was confused when I heard it for the first time. Luckily, a few English teachers and I were discussing on this topic a week back. That's why I remembered it!